# Print a value in wordpress within a page

Tags: php, wordpress

hello i am trying to print a value from the URL within a page on a WordPress site

i have edited the header.php and entered the following code

```
<?php
$town = rawurldecode( $_GET['town'] ); ?>
```

on the page i want to print the value i added

```
<?php print $town ?>
```

I have tried a few plugins that ment to allow php in the pages but i get errors

the url looks like this

```
website.co.uk/page/?town=abc
```

The results i was trying for was to use the PHP tag when i needed it within the page

for example

```
Hello i live in <?php print $town ?>, would you like to 
come see the football in <?php print $town ?>?.

Did you know that <?php print $town ?> is not that far?
```

Comment: which file are you modifying to do your print?

Comment: i was hoping to use the php tag when i needed it.. ill update my question

Comment: that doesnt tell me which page you're trying to modify

Comment: i changed the header.php and was trying to add the print function on a normal post/page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try to use [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Like so:

```
 $town = get_query_var('town');
 echo $town;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$town = rawurldecode( $_GET['town'] );`

to

`if(isset($_GET['town'])) { $town = rawurldecode( $_GET['town'] ); } else { $town = "No town"; }`

And change

`<?php print $town ?>`

to

`<?php echo $town; ?>`

Maybe this will work, please let us know the result.